# Events In Visual Studio 2010 (VB) for Login

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a question, what event do we use for textbox in login?

I want to make a LoginForm in my program where in when I type the Username and Password to the TextBoxes, I will use ENTER(in keyboard) instead of clicking the button 'Login'.

What events should I put these codes? :

```
 If txtUser.Text <> UsernameTextBox.Text And txtPass.Text <> PasswordTextBox.Text Then
     MsgBox("Wrong Username or Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
     txtUser.Text = ""
     txtPass.Text = ""
 Else
     ProgressBar1.Show()
     LoadLabel.Show()
     Timer1.Start()
 End If
```

Comment: Is there also a login button?

Comment: yup, there is a login button, but I want to make it like a facebook login wherein you just need to enter your correct User and Pass and then click "ENTER" on your keyboard and "PRESTO!"

Comment: Is this winforms, web app, wpf?

Comment: WindowsForm sir R0MANARMY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, the form's [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property:

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key.

To get the behavior you are looking for, just set the `AcceptButton` property on the form to the *log in* button (there's an example in the link) and put the code above into the regular [`OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx) event handler for the button.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much sir R0MANARMY :) your been a big help to me. THANK YOU!